# How to deploy private microservice in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-cloudformation

I'm new to Amazon services and I have a scenario to deploy microservice architecture. I just searched for many keywords but I've got nothing.
I have services A, B, C, D and I want to deploy them in a VPC cluster that has the Fargate launch type. I want to access each service by APIGateway Restful but I don't want to assign public IP to my services and I just want them to be accessed through API Gateway.

[image]

How could I do this by CloudFormation ?

Answer (score 0):

To create API gateway you can use [API Gatway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ApiGateway.html) resources from CloudFormatinon.

For load balancer you can use [ElasticLoadBalancingV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElasticLoadBalancingV2.html).

And for ECS you will need to use resources from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ECS.html).

All these resources have examples, which should help you get started.